# sql age stratifications

Tags: sql, select, case

I want to categorize age groups and display it in one column.

•   20–44 years.
•   45–64 years.
•   65 years and older.
•   Total.

These are the groups

I am unable to find total in the same column.

here i have use case statements but unable to find the total.

What I want to do is :

```
CASE
    WHEN Age >= 20 THEN 'TOTAL'
    WHEN Age >= 45 AND Age <= 64 THEN '45-64 YEARS'
    WHEN Age >= 65 THEN '65 YEARS AND OLDER'
    WHEN Age >= 20 AND Age <= 44 THEN '20-44 YEARS'
  END AS age_group,
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and share some simple data and the expected output ?

Comment: I want to do like this: CASE
    WHEN Age >= 20 THEN 'TOTAL'
    WHEN Age >= 45 AND Age <= 64 THEN '45-64 YEARS'
    WHEN Age >= 65 THEN '65 YEARS AND OLDER'
    WHEN Age >= 20 AND Age <= 44 THEN '20-44 YEARS'
  END AS age_group,

Comment: Hi - your question talks about totals but you haven’t explained what you are totalling- and are you counting whatever it is, summing it or what? Your case statement just generates “bucket” values; you haven’t explained what you want to put in the buckets

Answer (score 0):

The CASE will use the first option that evaluates to TRUE, so in the example code you gave, since `WHEN Age >= 20 THEN 'TOTAL'` is first then whenever Age is at least 20, it will always output `TOTAL` and nothing else.

To get both values for each group and also the total, you will need two separate queries. You can then use UNION to consolidate them into a single query if that is what you really need.

This query will get you the counts by group:

```sql
select
count(*) as count,
CASE
    WHEN Age >= 45 AND Age <= 64 THEN '45-64 YEARS'
    WHEN Age >= 65 THEN '65 YEARS AND OLDER'
    WHEN Age >= 20 AND Age <= 44 THEN '20-44 YEARS'
  END AS age_group
FROM ...
GROUP BY age_group
```

And this one for the total:

```sql
select
count(*) as count,
'TOTAL' AS age_group
FROM ...
```

And then to merge them into a single query:

```sql
select
count(*) as count,
CASE
    WHEN Age >= 45 AND Age <= 64 THEN '45-64 YEARS'
    WHEN Age >= 65 THEN '65 YEARS AND OLDER'
    WHEN Age >= 20 AND Age <= 44 THEN '20-44 YEARS'
  END AS age_group
FROM ...
GROUP BY age_group
UNION
select
count(*) as count,
'TOTAL' AS age_group
FROM ...
```